# Facebook API 2.8 / PHP / @Mention on Post

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have the following script and would like to mention for ex. another page, which is involved in the post. I tried severall things, but can´ get it work. Isn´t it possible?

Here is my script:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __DIR__.'/src/Facebook/');
require_once(__DIR__.'/src/Facebook/autoload.php');

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
 'app_id' => ‚1*************‘,
 'app_secret' => ‚*e************,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$params["message"] = "Here is the magic - Thanks for your support, @[pageid]";
$params["link"] = "";
$params["picture"] = "";
$params["description"] = ";;


$pageAccessToken ='**************************';

try {
 $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $params, $pageAccessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
 echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
 exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
 echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
 exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

I tried, using **@[pageid]** and **@[page-id:page-name]**, but both is not working. 
Would be great to get any help.

Comment: let us know what is the exact message you are getting of follow my answer below.

Comment: No error appears, when i add / change your code.

Comment: Did you pay attention to the limitations on this feature as mentioned in the docs for /page/feed?

Comment: Which "limitations" do you mean? I checked it, but i didn´t find any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I will say error from facebook is always different based on configuration of your app, page etc. So it is difficult to say without seeing the exact error message. Just change your code a little bit to see error message is details:

```
try {
   $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $params, $pageAccessToken);
   } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
   echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
   exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
   var_dump($e);
    exit;
   }
```

I am sure, you will get error details which will guide you to solve your problem.

Comment: I just checked it - no error appears, when i ad var_dump. Any other idea?